# aspnet 5 mvc 6 refrencing existing class library

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way I can reference an existing class library or project into my aspnet5 mvc6 webapi project? when i try that I am getting this error...my class library is build on 4.6.1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using DNX Version 46 in your project.json and remove the dnxcore section completely.